# Convolutional neural network doesn't classify test set keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I have a 3-D convolutional neural network [keras, tensorflow] and 3D brain images of people with advanced alzheimer's, early alzheimer's and healthy people (3 classes). I have training set of 324 images and test set of 74 images. When I trained my CNN, I had about 65-70% accuracy but for the test set I had only 30-40%. When I used the test data as validation data then for training set I had no more than 37% accuracy as well and the loss stayed at the same level the whole time. Nevermind which parameters I change, the result is the same. I load my prepared and normalized data from .h5 file into Python, and the input have shape (None, 90, 120, 80, 1). I don't have an idea what may be wrong, I checked the code many times and everything seems to be correct.

My CNN have 4 conv3D layers, 3 max-pooling, activations:relu and batch_normalizations, 3 dense layers and dropout, softmax

I appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Maybe you've got a very biased test set. You selected too many specific cases for the test set. Since your data is small, that is not rare to happen. Check if your test data and your train data have a similar proportion of healthy/early/advanced cases.

Comment: the data have similar proportion :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 65/70% accuracy on your training data that is really poor and indicates your neural network is not converging properly. Your network should be capable of at least overfitting the training data if the structure is complex enough, by effectively learning to hardcode the outputs from the small input sample. By the sound of it, your structure is complex enough.

The first thing to try is to reduce the learning rate by a factor of 10, and turn off validation/early stopping/normalisation/regularisation and any other ways to prevent overfitting. Then rinse, repeat - more iterations, each reducing the LR by a factor of 10 - until you can overfit the training data to where it gets close to 100% on the training data.

You can then work on putting in the proper early stopping, dropout, normalisation, regularisation etc to prevent overfitting with a learning rate you know works.

If dropping the LR doesn't even overfit however small the LR then you have some issue with your NN structure.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. I have poor accuracy indeed, but I know that my data is complex and I don't know if I can reach even 85% accuracy. All I want for now, is my CNN work (that means at least 60-70% for test set).